# alert uuid= does not exist. dropping to a shell

Tags: boot, bios

I am a new Ubuntu user. After an automatic update and reboot, Ubuntu does not boot and gives an `alert uuid= does not exist. dropping to a shell` error. There are a lot of important files on the system which I don't want to lose.

I started the Ubuntu live USB, entered the `fdisk -l` command, and my main hard drive does not appear in the output. It shows only the partition of the bootable flash drive. Could this mean that the main SSD on which Ubuntu is installed is broken?

Before `built-in shell (ash)` is loaded, it gives several errors.

```
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
scsi 16:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
scsi 16:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
```

Since my operating system won't boot, I'm currently in a built-in shell.

Results of `lsb_release -a` :

```
lsb_release -a not found 

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.4) built-in shell (ash)
```

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; but I'd not expect any system upgrade to cause changes to UUID's; that's more likely user change, or hardware change including problems with hardware.. so I'd boot *live* media & validate your drive's health (SMART) & partition health for your *unstated* OS & *unstated* release.  You've provided too little details (no OS product/release details) for anything specific though.

Comment: Linux 5.13.0-30-generic(5.13.0-28-generic)

Comment: That's a kernel; a kernel that is used by multiple OSes & releases, so you've still not provided clues as to what OS & release you're actually using (*that kernel is used by on-topic Ubuntu systems as well as non-Ubuntu systems*)

Comment: How to view system version from terminal?

Comment: It can be viewed in many ways; `lsb_release -a` is what I'd use (`-a` will display all details of linux standard base release info).  Also if providing more details, please edit & add them to your question. Comments are intended for us to ask you questions; once you've provided that detail we remove the comments (*makes your question easier to read & you'll usually get more readers & hopefully faster answers*)

Comment: Since my system won't boot, I'm currently in built-in shell. The command doesn't work in this shell, writes "lsb_release -a not found"

Comment: BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.4) built-in shell (ash)

Comment: I started the Ubuntu Live USB, entered the fdisk -l command, my main hard drive is not in the information. Shows only the partition of the bootable flash drive. Could this mean that the main ssd on which the main Ubuntu was installed is broken, or it should not show up in the boot version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I mentioned SMART in my first comment which is best run from *live* media.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools will likely be helpful, but GUI tools exist too (so you don't need to use the command line tool); ie. `gnome-disk-utility`, KDE Partition Manager, etc. A missing UUID as I stated in that first comment is usually the result of hardware OR a user-initiated change which could be anything from changed setting in BIOS/uEFI etc. As SMART is read from electronics, you usually get results even if drive is unusable (*only power to the electronics is required*) but not bad cables

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. In the BIOS, I changed the virtualization settings, I had it enabled, I did this in order for the virtual machines to work. I turned it off and the system booted up, but the virtual machines stopped working, but I think I can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the virtualization settings in the BIOS which you enabled in order for the virtual machines to work and try to boot without them enabled.